# Ruby - what does Array.any?(&:nil?) mean?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and working through a tutorial but am not sure what this line of code means:

```
[movie, version_number].any?(&:nil?)
```

From my research, `Array.any?` returns true if any of the elements of the array are not `false` or `nil`. And `&:nil?` means to call `to_proc()` on the symbol `:nil?` i.e. `:nil?.to_proc` so the statement is equivalent to

```
[movie, version_number].any?(:nil?.to_proc)
```

which is equivalent to

```
[movie, version_number].any?{|item| item.nil?}
```

Further, `any?` Passes each element of the collection (in this case, Array) to the `{|item| item.nil?}` block.

When you put them together, does the line of code mean, call `nil?` on each element in the Array before calling `.any?` on the array, i.e. is it equivalent to:

```
[movie.nil?, version_number.nil?].any?
```

Or, in plain English, are *any* of *movie* or *version_number* equivalent to *nil*?

Comment: "And `&:nil?` means to call `to_proc()` on the symbol `:nil?`" - and does this _say_ anything to you? What does `:nil?.to_proc` do/produce? If you don't know, I can't believe you were satisfied with this definition and stopped digging further.

Comment: I mean, you may have stopped researching prematurely. As you may know, most everything in ruby is an expression. `2 + 3` evaluates to `5`. If you call `foo(2 + 3)` or `foo(5)`, then `foo` won't notice the difference because the value is the same. Similarly, `:nil?.to_proc` is also an expression. But what does it evaluate to? Is it something that `.any?` can use? What kinds of values/parameters can you pass to `.any?` that could affect its return value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Symbol#to_proc documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

> Returns a Proc object which respond to the given method by sym.
>
> ```
> (1..3).collect(&:to_s)  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
> ```

So in your case this is effectively the same as writing:

```
[movie, version_number].any?{|item| item.nil? }
```

`any?` expects a block<sup>[1]</sup> to be passed, which will be evaluated for each item, and will return true if the block evaluates to true for any of the members.

The `to_proc` method on Symbol is basically a convenience shortcut, when you just want to call a single method on the item passed to the block. As in the example above, this leads to shorter code than explicitly defining the block.

<sup>[1]</sup> Refer [this article](http://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) on blocks, procs and lambdas in ruby

Comment: ok thanks, but what does `[movie, version_number].any?{|item| item.nil? }` mean?

Comment: I have elaborated on the anwer.

Comment: ok so does that mean my interpretation in the original question is correct? i'm not able to figure out from your answer (sorry if sounds stupid)

Comment: It is conceptually correct. But the implementation does not create an intermediate array with results of `nil?`. For most enumerables, the implementation of `any?` is short-circuited, so as soon as the block evaluates to true it will return true.

Comment: I would drop "effectively", as the ampersand operator does two things when acting on a symbol: it invokes [Symbol#to_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) and then converts the newly-created proc to a block. Without the second step the expression would just return the proc, rather than compute and return the value of the block.